# I can't open form designer in windows form project c# with DevExpress

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2017, devexpress, windows-forms-designer

i can't open form designer in windows form project c# with DevExpress.
The project is work fine and without errors but i can't open designer of all forms 
and the designer shows me  **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**
So, can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Usually when you dismiss that error, Visual Studio will give some insight as to why you received it. Look at the output window for clues. The error you see means that the designer code backing your form contains an error when the designer framework is trying to render a control at design-time. Try opening the .cs file for your form in Visual Studio and inspect it for any issues. Also, inspect your project references and make sure that all of the DevExpress references are getting resolved properly. If I had to guess, I suspect that one of your DevExpress references no longer is resolving.

Comment: i restarted my machine but nothing changed , the problem is remaining 
im workin on visual studio 2017 
this is the project that has the problem : 
 http://www.4shared.com/rar/DMC1rOIHee/Copy.html 
So , any expert on this forum can download the project and solve my problem 
can anyone help me please?

Comment: You need to work with us. I gave you several suggestions to investigate and report back on and you seemed only to reset your machine, which I already said wouldn't likely work. Downloading your code isn't necessarily going to reveal the problem because, as I explained, it likely has to do with how DevExpress components are registered on your system.

Comment: Can anyone give me Devexpress 16.1.7 ? because  i have not this version and i installed 16.1.6 on  my machine  and maybe it causes this problem

Comment: You can download older versions including v16.1.7 from the DevExpress [download manager](https://www.devexpress.com/ClientCenter/DownloadManager/). Just change the version drop down to the version that you require. As long as you had a valid 16.1 license, you will have access to all minor 16.1 versions. See also: [Download a Registered Product](https://www.devexpress.com/support/order/)

Comment: thank you @Brendon , but i dont have license , i use trail version , so the version dropdown dose not appear for me. can u give trial version ?

Comment: No, trial versions are not available for out-of-date versions. You can try installing the 18.2 trial version for a 30 day evaluation or purchase a license, which will give you access to previous versions.

Answer (score -2):

Could be a problem with visual studio. Try restarting your machine.

Comment: This is very likely not a "restart your machine" issue.

Comment: Or it could be, even visual studio has bugs.